# Personalization issue

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, ax, dynamics-ax-2012-r2

I had personalized the columns in the Sales Order Grid, I had added some columns and I had arranged them in a manner that is easy for me to identify. I had also saved my changes.

This is working fine but when I navigate to other forms and come back to Sales Order form, the changes that I've made are all gone. The columns are not arranged. This started to happen after we upgraded to Dynamics 2012 R2. What seems to be the cause of this issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turned out to be an issue with AX 2012 after the R2 upgrade. There is a hotfix for this which can be found in the customer source site. Downloaded and installed the hotfix and the issue is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

This is called ["User Personalization"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa635528.aspx) and is a function of AX's Intellimorph.

When you make changes to your form, the changes are packed and saved in a table called `SysLastValue` which stores your user-specific usage data.  When you open a form, it unpacks the saved settings that specifically match whatever form you are using.

When you upgraded from AX 2012 to AX 2012 R2, the form likely changed and has extra fields or something.  Well when AX tries to unpack your saved usage data, the packed data doesn't match how it's now expecting it to be unpacked...so it doesn't work.

So what you need to do is make your changes again and then those will replace the old changes and should persist.  If the form is modified in the future, or you clear your usage data (which empties the SysLastValue table for your user), you might run into the same issue with your personalization missing.

If there is a lot of personalization or the personalization is a common change for all users, then you should consider having a developer make these changes permanently on the form.

Comment: it is not a common change, there is a lot of personalization, different user different personalization, not sure how the developer can make the changes permanently, is that something the developer can do?

Comment: If it is not a common change, then just make your changes again and they should stay.  AX2012 vs AX2012R2 is a big version change.  It's like saying I bought custom seat covers for my 2005 Honda Accord, and now I have a 2012 Honda accord and the seat covers don't fit.  Just get new seat covers and then you're done.  When I said "common change", pretend every Honda owner was putting a headrest on their car...then a developer should put a headrest on every honda seat that leaves the factory.

Comment: that's the problem, I had made my changes again and again yet the problem still exists, all the changes I've made are all wiped out when I navigate to other forms and return to the page I'm working on.

Comment: If these changes are that important to you, you should have a developer help you with this.  You might try resetting your usage data, then remaking your changes and seeing if they persist.  Warning though, when you reset your usage data, all of your form personalizations across the entire system for your user are reset. If you made changes to many forms, then this might be a pain. If you only change a couple forms, then it shouldn't be too bad.

Comment: that's also the problem, I'm the developer (newbie here) and I'm trying to fix this issue for our client. I had thought about resetting the usage data but that will only be the last resort. Can you give me a link on how to make these changes permanently on the form?

Comment: You can reset the usage data for this specific form for this specific user: open the `SysLastValue` form, the `All usage data tab`, filter by the `Record type`, `Element name` and `User ID`, and then delete the records.

Comment: I have reset the usage data but still the issue occurs. I Also deleted the AUC files, that didn't work either. I noticed that its only the newly added columns that always moved to the left every time I go out and back to the Sales order page, I still don't know why.

Comment: Are you making these changes by right clicking the form, then selecting `Personalize`? When you reset the usage data, you realize it's stored on a per-user basis.  So are you making these customizations on another user's computer and then looking on your machine?  When you make the customizations they should stay after closing the form.  You can try saving them by clicking "save" and giving them a name. Then you can try from another user, clicking `retrieve from user` and retrieving or saving them.

Comment: Yes, I'm making the changes by selecting personalize. I am using my machine to try to fix the issue, as I can replicate it on my machine. I understand that it is a per user basis, and that I had saved my changes and gave it a name yet the columns keep on rearranging for whatever reason. the newly added columns all sort to the left before the default columns after closing/opening the form, even though I had a arranged them in a different manner. Yes the changes should stay but apparently they are not.

Comment: Sounds like a code bug or a Microsoft bug. You can write a job that you run to query the SysLastValue table and do `conView(SysLastValue.value)` before you make your changes, as you make your changes, after you close the personalization form, and after the changes apparently get reverted and compare the containers and see if the data actually is changing or it's something else.

Comment: I wrote a job, and the Syslastvalue gets updated, the newly saved personalization say SalesTableListpage is saved, and a new record is created for that element name and it has a design name also. after closing the form, there are no updates for the said element name. The updates only occur after saving the personalization. I'm trying to find out any property for the grid that makes the newly added columns shift to the left side or anything that could explain why it is behaving that way.

Comment: At this point it sounds like a debugging issue and I've probably answered this question and we're starting to go outside the scope.  Maybe mark this question as answered and post a new question once you find more details and you can post more information.